# WebApi cannot return DTO that contains a list of another DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dto

I have a invoice DTO that I want to return that contains a list of invoice items where InvoiceLines is the junction table.

My WebApi controller code:

```
var screenset =
    from inv in context.Invoices where inv.InvoiceId == invoiceID
    join line in context.InvoiceLines on inv.InvoiceId equals line.InvoiceId
    join track in context.Tracks on line.TrackId equals track.TrackId into T
    select new InvoiceDTO
    {
        InvoiceId = inv.InvoiceId,
        InvoiceDate = inv.InvoiceDate,
        CustomerId = inv.CustomerId,
        CustomerFullName = inv.Customer.LastName + ", " + inv.Customer.FirstName,
        CustomerPhoneNumber = inv.Customer.Phone,
        BillingAddress = inv.BillingAddress,
        BillingCity = inv.BillingCity,
        BillingState = inv.BillingState,
        BillingCountry = inv.BillingCountry,
        BillingPostalCode = inv.BillingPostalCode,
        Tracks = T.Select(t => new InvoiceTrackDTO
        {
            InvoiceLineId = line.InvoiceLineId,
            TrackId = t.TrackId,
            TrackName = t.Name,
            Artist = t.Album.Artist.Name,
            UnitPrice = line.UnitPrice,
            Quantity = line.Quantity
        })
    };

    var result = screenset.SingleOrDefault();
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    return response;
```

My DTO's are defined as follows:

```
public class InvoiceDTO
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerFullName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public string BillingCity { get; set; }
    public string BillingState { get; set; }
    public string BillingCountry { get; set; }
    public string BillingPostalCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceTrackDTO> Tracks { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceTrackDTO
{
    public int InvoiceLineId { get; set; }
    public int TrackId { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

My consumer code is:

```
message = new HttpClient().GetMessage(host, path, q).Result;
invoice = message.GetObjectFromMessage<InvoiceDTO>().Result;
tracks = invoice.Tracks as IEnumerable<InvoiceTrackDTO>;
```

My problem is if the ApiController is called with .ToList() it will give an error:

```
var result = screenset.ToList();
```

If the ApiController returns with .SingleOrDefault() it sucessfully returns the invoice but the invoice items cannot be more than one.

```
var result = screenset.SingleOrDefault();
```

I am trying to get a single invoice based on its ID but the invoice contains a list of invoice items.

So is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

If I do this in the consumer:

```
message = new HttpClient().GetMessage(host, path, q).Result;
invoice = message.GetObjectFromMessage<InvoiceDTO>().Result;
Debug.WriteLine("Invoice: " + invoice.ToJsonString());
tracks = invoice.Tracks as IEnumerable<InvoiceTrackDTO>;
Debug.WriteLine("Tracks: " + tracks.ToJsonString());
```

where `ToJsonString` is my extension method to convert any object to Json string. I can get invoice but not tracks where tracks are the invoice items.

The output and error I'm getting is as follows:

> Invoice: {"InvoiceId":0,"InvoiceDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","CustomerId":0,"CustomerFullName":null,"CustomerPhoneNumber":null,"BillingAddress":null,"BillingCity":null,"BillingState":null,"BillingCountry":null,"BillingPostalCode":null,"Tracks":null}
>
> Tracks: null
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll

**EDIT 2:**
Ok, just to clear things up a little.

I am comparing inner join with group join as illustrated below:

```
Parent  
Id  Value  
1   A  
2   B  
3   C  

Child  
Id  ChildValue  
1   a1  
1   a2  
1   a3  
2   b1  
2   b2
```

### Inner Join

```
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.Id equals c.Id
select new { p.Value, c.ChildValue }

Result  
Value ChildValue  
A     a1  
A     a2  
A     a3  
B     b1  
B     b2
```

### GroupJoin

```
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.Id equals c.Id into g
select new { Parent = p, Children = g }

Result  
Value  ChildValues  
A      [a1, a2, a3]  
B      [b1, b2]  
C      []
```

When returning from Entity Framework using LINQ, inner join works but not the group join.

Group join will be returned like inner join.

Hope that clarifies my question :)

Comment: Of course it's possible. You imply you get an error. Have you looked at what the error actually says?

Comment: Why did I get a down vote without getting any comments or answers?

Comment: What is the error message you get? Is it a compilation error or a run-time error?

Comment: It's a runtime error. No exception thrown at the ApiController end. I have updated my question with the error I'm getting.

Comment: Have you verified that the data you get out of the LINQ statement is correct, before it is sent to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized the problem. Entity Framework ultimately generates SQL based on Linq. In SQL, there is no notion of a parent object containing a list of child objects. Number of records returned will be the number of child objects with the parent columns repeated.

I was in a rush initially and forgot that a simple browser or Fiddler output will show that the original ApiController method will return this:

[image: Single object containing child objects]

So modify your DTO like this:

```
public class InvoiceAndItemsDTO
{
    // Invoice
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerFullName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public string BillingCity { get; set; }
    public string BillingState { get; set; }
    public string BillingCountry { get; set; }
    public string BillingPostalCode { get; set; }
    // Track
    public int InvoiceLineId { get; set; }
    public int TrackId { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And modify your ApiController method like this:

```
var screenset =
from inv in context.Invoices where inv.InvoiceId == invoiceID
join line in context.InvoiceLines on inv.InvoiceId equals line.InvoiceId
join track in context.Tracks on line.TrackId equals track.TrackId
select new InvoiceAndItemsDTO
{
    InvoiceId = inv.InvoiceId,
    InvoiceDate = inv.InvoiceDate,
    CustomerId = inv.CustomerId,
    CustomerFullName = inv.Customer.LastName + ", " +       inv.Customer.FirstName,
    CustomerPhoneNumber = inv.Customer.Phone,
    BillingAddress = inv.BillingAddress,
    BillingCity = inv.BillingCity,
    BillingState = inv.BillingState,
    BillingCountry = inv.BillingCountry,
    BillingPostalCode = inv.BillingPostalCode,
    InvoiceLineId = line.InvoiceLineId,
    TrackId = track.TrackId,
    TrackName = track.Name,
    Artist = track.Album.Artist.Name,
    UnitPrice = line.UnitPrice,
    Quantity = line.Quantity
};
```

and your consumer like this:

```
message = new HttpClient().GetMessage(host, path, q).Result;
tracks = message.GetObjectFromMessage<List<InvoiceAndItemsDTO>>().Result;
if (tracks != null)
{
    invoice = tracks.First();
}
```